# Wifi Not Working In kali Linux

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, usb, virtualbox

I have a Kali Linux virtual machine (VirtualBox) I'm trying to get my wireless card working in. I've tried installing the drivers, but when looking it up on Google, most people seem to think I have to buy a USB wireless adapter for it to work.

I found a video with a guy who claims you can get this to work if you boot Kali from a live USB stick instead of using VirtualBox. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. The reason you can't use your built-in wireless card when running Kali in VirtualBox is that your wireless card most likely uses PCI(e) which VirtualBox doesn't support passing to your virtual machine.

When booting Kali from a USB stick, Kali will have direct access to your wireless card, and as such it'll work.

Comment: ok thank you. Means from usb boot it will support any wireless card in my laptop??

Comment: Means if i use kali linux from usb boot i can scan wireless networks with in my laptop range without any usb apdater right?

Comment: As long as you have the appropriate drivers, yes.

Comment: ok.Means not every laptop network card work on kali linux live boot right??